# iOS : Use setDateFormat as 12 hour clock

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I need set DateFormat for the time as 12 hour clock , I don't know how to set it ,this code shows 24 hour clock :

```
  NSDateFormatter *timeFormater = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];   
 [timeFormater setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSDateFormatter *timeFormater = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[timeFormater setDateFormat:@"h:mm:ss a"]
```

Try that.

Comment: What on earth?  Why did you alloc a date formatter, only to set it to ANOTHER date formatter from an init method?  Why not just use `NSDateFormatter* timeFormatter = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"hh:mm:ss a"];`?

Comment: This is redundant. Rather do as @Tim suggested. The inner class method creates an additional instance of `NSDateFormatter` unnecessarily.

Comment: Not to mention this code isn't even right... `+dateFormatFromTemplate:options:locale:` is the method signature and it *requires* the locale. At best, this code won't compile (depending on compiler you choose and settings), at worst it will crash when you send that message to the `NSDateFormatter`.

Comment: Removed downvote as the answer was edited (to something VERY familiar) --v

Answer (score 4):

```
NSDateFormatter *timeFormater = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];   
[timeFormater setDateFormat:@"h:mm:ss a"]
```

Or, if you prefer a two-digit hour:

```
NSDateFormatter *timeFormater = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];   
[timeFormater setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss a"]
```

Comment: One `h` will result in a time like 1:35, whereas two `h`'s will result in 01:35.  `a` becomes AM or PM.

Answer (score 1):

Use `[timeFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss"]`

Answer (score 1):

Use lower case `hh` to get 12 hour and upper case `HH` for 24 hour. [Here's the guide](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns)